# how to play rtmp in c# UWP application

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, rtmp

i wanna know how can i play rtmp streams in my c# universal application for windows 10?
link: rtmp://live.video.asandl.com/devices//tv3-300k.stream

with MediaElement i can play http://live.tv.asandl.com:1935/devices/tv3-300k.stream/chunklist_w1286632381.m3u8 (its not working till yesterday , they changed stream method to rtmp) but no chance on playing rtmp.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FFmpegInterop library for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop) to play rtmp streams in UWP apps.

To create appropriate MediaStreamSource for MediaElement you should use method **FFmepgInteropMSS.CreateFFmpegInteropMSSFromUri**.

More details here: [Using the FFmpegInterop object](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop/blob/master/README.md#using-the-ffmpeginterop-object).

Comment: thank you for quick response but , i saw that in its sample you have to choose local file !!!!!!! honestly i donno how to use it :( can you plz help?

Comment: OMG i have to do these steps https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT to get one or 2 dll ?!!!!!!!!! there isnt a dll to just refference to it !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! im just so confused :|

Comment: well i did everything this page said to build ffmpeg but get some errors, i email them about this error, i will return if they answer, thanks again